# For a multiclassed Wizard/Sorcerer, do the Wizard school features benefit sorcerer spells?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, wizard, multi-classing, sorcerer

If I'm primarily a sorcerer and multiclass into a wizard of the school [Evocation/Admixture](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/arcane-schools/paizo-arcane-schools/classic-arcane-schools/evocation/admixture/), with this effect:

> Versatile Evocation (Su): **When you cast an evocation spell** that does
>   acid, cold, electricity, or fire damage, you may change the damage
>   dealt to one of the other four energy types. This changes the
>   descriptor of the spell to match the new energy type. Any non-damaging
>   effects remain unchanged unless the new energy type invalidates them
>   (an ice storm that deals fire damage might still provide a penalty on
>   Perception checks due to smoke, but it would not create difficult
>   terrain). Such effects are subject to GM discretion. You can use this
>   ability a number of times per day equal to 3 + your Intelligence
>   modifier.

Can I use this effect when casting sorcerer evocation spells to change the damage type?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The relevant rules are found in [this FAQ](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9ne8):

> #### Sorcerer: Do the bonuses granted from Bloodline Arcana apply to all of the spells cast by the sorcerer, or just those cast from the sorcerer's spell list?
>
> The Bloodline Arcana powers apply to all of the spells cast by characters of that bloodline, not just those cast using the sorcerer's spell slots.
>
> General rule: If a class ability modifies your spellcasting, it applies to your spells from all classes, not just spells from the class that grants the ability. (The exception is if the class ability specifically says it only applies to spells from that class.)

This specifies the opposite interaction, and the answer there is yes. More importantly, it also gives us a rule for figuring out other interactions: do the wizard’s spell school features specify that they only work for wizard spells? Versatile evocation does not. Thus it works for sorcerer spells too.